# Approximate solution for integration of two Bessel Functions

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

I am an engineering student. I have encountered a problem during my thesis study. I need to find $F(x)$ in terms of $G(y)$ which is a function of $(n-1)$. degree polynomial. My statement as follows:
$$\int_{0}^\infty F(x)[B\,x^3J_0(xy)+x^4J_1(xy)]dx=G(y)$$
where B is a constant, and $J_0$ and $J_1$ are the Bessel functions of the first kind. If $B$ was equal to zero, $F(x)$ could be found using Hankel transform as follows:
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{x^3} \int_{0}^\infty G(y) J_1(xy)y\,dy$$
However $B$ is not zero, therefore I could not take Hankel Transform directly. Is there any approximate solution in which I can represent $F(x)$ in terms of $G(y)$ such that
 $$F(x)=H(x) \int_{0}^\infty G(y) J_1(xy)y\,dy$$
 Thanks.

Comment: Why this new question? You should update your old one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749270/integration-of-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind